# How to save and retrieve data on Ethereum blockchain with Solidity and Web.js

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

The below code only returns a receipt but I want it to return a tuple of data, like in the contract below. How do I get it to return the data? I can't find a good tutorial on how to save and retrieve data. I know this is an expensive use case, I'm just trying to do a basic proof of concept and learn at the same time.

I'm using web3@1.0.0-beta.29

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  dappUrl: string = 'http://myapp.com';
  web3: any;
  contractHash: string = '0x3b8a60616bde6f6d251e807695900f31ab12ce1a';
  MyContract: any;
  contract: any;
  ABI: any = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"idx","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getLocationHistory","outputs":[{"name":"delegate","type":"address"},{"name":"longitude","type":"uint128"},{"name":"latitude","type":"uint128"},{"name":"name","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"recentLocation","outputs":[{"name":"delegate","type":"address"},{"name":"longitude","type":"uint128"},{"name":"latitude","type":"uint128"},{"name":"name","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"longitude","type":"uint128"},{"name":"latitude","type":"uint128"},{"name":"name","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"saveLocation","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"getLastLocation","outputs":[{"components":[{"name":"delegate","type":"address"},{"name":"longitude","type":"uint128"},{"name":"latitude","type":"uint128"},{"name":"name","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"recentLocation","type":"tuple"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"locations","outputs":[{"name":"delegate","type":"address"},{"name":"longitude","type":"uint128"},{"name":"latitude","type":"uint128"},{"name":"name","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"item","outputs":[{"name":"id","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"name","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"id","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"name","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"}];


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  @HostListener('window:load')
  windowLoaded() {
    this.checkAndInstantiateWeb3();
    this.getLocation();
  }

  getLocationHistory() {
    this.MyContract.methods
      .getLocationHistory(0).send({
      'from': '0x902D578B7E7866FaE71b3AB0354C9606631bCe03',
      'gas': '44000'
    }).then((result) => {
      this.MyContract.methods.getLocationHistory(0).call()
        .then(hello => {console.log('hello', hello)});
    });
  }

  private checkAndInstantiateWeb3 = () => {
    if (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
      console.warn('Using web3 detected from external source.');
      // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
      this.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      console.warn(`No web3 detected. Falling back to http://localhost:8545.`);
      this.web3 = new Web3(
        new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545')
      );
    }

    this.MyContract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(this.ABI, this.contractHash);
  }

  private getLocation(): void {
    let query = this.route.snapshot.queryParams;

    if (query.action && query.action === 'setLocation') {
      this.setLocation();
    }

  }

  private setLocation(): void {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {

      this.MyContract.methods.saveLocation(
        position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude, window.web3.fromAscii("test")
      ).send({'from': '0x902D578B7E7866FaE71b3AB0354C9606631bCe03'}
      ).then((result) => {
        console.log('saveLocation')
        console.log(result)
      });

      this.getLocationHistory();

    });
  }    

}
```

Solidity Contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
/// @title QRCodeTracking with delegation.
contract QRCodeTracking {
    struct Location {
        address delegate;
        uint128 longitude;
        uint128 latitude; 
        bytes32 name;
    }

    struct Item {
        bytes32 id;   
        bytes32 name; 
    }

    Item public item;

    Location[] public locations;
    Location public recentLocation;

    function QRCodeTracking(bytes32 id, bytes32 name) public {
        // Limit gas
        locations.length = 100;
        item = Item({id: id, name: name});
    }

    function saveLocation (
        uint128 longitude,
        uint128 latitude,
        bytes32 name
    ) public constant {

        locations.push(Location({
            delegate: msg.sender,
            longitude: longitude,
            latitude: latitude,
            name: name
        }));

    }

    function getLocationHistory(uint idx) constant
        returns (address delegate, uint128 longitude, uint128 latitude, bytes32 name) {

        Location storage loc = locations[idx];

        return (loc.delegate, loc.longitude, loc.latitude, loc.name);
    }

    function getLastLocation() public
        returns (Location recentLocation) {
        recentLocation = locations[locations.length - 1];

        return recentLocation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem occur when you call `this.MyContract.methods.saveLocation`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code that center around the use of `constant` functions and understanding the difference between `send` and `call` in web3.

In Solidity, the `constant` (or `view`) modifier is used to mark contract functions that don't change state (see [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#view-functions)). If you attempt to update contract state in a `constant` function, the state change will not persist. Therefore, in your Solidity contract, `saveLocation` should NOT be `constant`. However, both `getLastLocation` and `getLocationHistory` only read from state, so those should both be `constant`.

On the client side, you have the same distinction when calling a contract function using web3. You use `send` when you want to execute a transaction on the blockchain, but use `call` when you want to retrieve data from your contract.

When you use `this.MyContract.methods.getLocationHistory(0).send()`, you are executing a transaction against your contract and the transaction receipt is sent back via the callback passed in (or via a `.then` Promise). Web3 documentation for send can be found [here](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send). Important note - nothing from the contract state can be returned from a Solidity function that executes a transaction. If you have `returns` in a non-constant function, it will compile, but the data is not returned. The only way to return data from the contract is to use `constant` functions or by using [events](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events). For your use case, you want to use `this.MyContract.methods.getLocationHistory(0).call()`. [Call web3 documentation.](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call)

EDIT - Adding simplified test client. Notice the use of `send` vs `call`.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const solc = require('solc');
const fs = require('fs');

const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545")
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

web3.eth.getAccounts().then((accounts) => {
  const code = fs.readFileSync('./QRCodeTracking.sol').toString();
  const compiledCode = solc.compile(code);

  const byteCode = compiledCode.contracts[':QRCodeTracking'].bytecode;
  // console.log('byteCode', byteCode);
  const abiDefinition = JSON.parse(compiledCode.contracts[':QRCodeTracking'].interface);

  const deployTransactionObject = {
    data: byteCode,
    from: accounts[0],
    gas: 4700000
  };

  let deployedContract;

  const MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiDefinition, deployTransactionObject);

  MyContract.deploy({arguments: [web3.utils.asciiToHex("someId"), web3.utils.asciiToHex("someName")]}).send((err, hash) => {
    if (err)
      console.log("Error: " + err);
    else
      console.log("TX Hash: " + hash);
  }).then(result => {
    deployedContract = result;
    deployedContract.setProvider(provider);

    return deployedContract.methods.saveLocation(123456789, 987654321, web3.utils.asciiToHex("newLocationName")).send();
  }).then(saveResult => {
    return deployedContract.methods.getLocationHistory(0).call();
  }).then(locationResult => {
    console.log(locationResult);
  })
});
```

Comment: Are you saying .call() will return the data? .call() only returns locally, it doesn't access the blockchain. –

Comment: That's not correct. It doesn't publish to the blockchain, but it executes within the EVM and does indeed read from it. If you're running a local node, then the invocation runs locally and you don't pay for the gas used.

Comment: Ok, but it still doesn't return my data, which is my original question.

Comment: Just noticed the other bug you have: `locations.length = 100;` is creating 100 elements in your `locations` array all initialized with fields set to 0. When you call `saveLocation`, you're adding an element to your array at index 100. When you retrieve the element at index 0, you're getting an all 0 location object. Remove that line. After making that change (plus the others I mentioned), I tested the contract and it ran. I updated the answer with my own version of the client that's a little more straightforward.

Comment: Ok, great thanks.  I initially put that in because Remix IDE wouldn't compile and found a stackoverflow post that said to set the length to avoid the infinite recursion error that Remix was throwing.  Glad I lost three days of work over a Remix IDE bug.  Now it works in Remix no problem.  Ugh..