# Web3.js returned error: execution reverted

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I'm new to blockchain programming and web3 and I don't really understand the error.
I'm trying to call a function from my smart contract (on BSC test net)

Function is called `getRandom`

app.js

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3("https://speedy-nodes-nyc.moralis.io/redacted/bsc/testnet");
const key = "28e........................8"
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract([
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getRandom",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
], "0x22191A37B2AB83e7A81758ecd0E120cf080153B1")

const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('0x' + key);
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account);

(async () => {
    try {
        const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
        const gasEstimate = await contract.methods.getRandom().estimateGas({from: account.address});

        console.log(contract.methods.getRandom().send({from: account.address, gasPrice: gasPrice, gas: gasEstimate}))
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
})();
```

Error

```
Error: Returned error: execution reverted
    at Object.ErrorResponse (C:\DeFi project\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:28:19)
    at C:\DeFi project\node_modules\web3-core-requestmanager\lib\index.js:302:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\DeFi project\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib\index.js:98:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\DeFi project\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\DeFi project\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\DeFi project\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\DeFi project\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:289:61)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  data: null
}
```

I'm just trying to get the response from my smart contract's function.

Comment: I've the same problem on BSC Testnet and Ropsten Test net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a logical error in your `getRandom` method. Here is a working code for the same problem.

And if you just want to retrive a random number from the contract then you can just use `call` method.

Check here for the basic understanding of how `send` and `call` method works:
[How to save and retrieve data on Ethereum blockchain with Solidity and Web.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603051/how-to-save-and-retrieve-data-on-ethereum-blockchain-with-solidity-and-web-js)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

/**
 * @title Storage
 * @dev Store & retrieve value in a variable
 */
contract Storage {

    uint256 number;
    /**
     * @dev Store value in variable
     * @param num value to store
     */
    function store(uint256 num) public {
        number = num;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Return value 
     * @return value of 'number'
     */
    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256){
        return number;
    }
    
    /**
     * @dev Return value 
     * @return value of 'number'
     */
    function getRandom() public view returns (uint){
        return uint(keccak256(block.difficulty, now));
    }
}
```

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3("https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545");
const key = "YOUR_WALLET_KEY_HERE"
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract([
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "retrieve",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "num",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "store",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getRandom",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
], "0xc48a2E92F3F2066153a3eDDf5071bc0C1Ece0172")

const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('0x' + key);
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account);

(async () => {
    try {
        const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
        const value = Web3.utils.toHex('5');
        const gasEstimate = await contract.methods.store(value).estimateGas({from: account.address});
        console.log(await contract.methods.store(value).send({from: account.address, gasPrice: gasPrice, gas: gasEstimate}));
        console.log(await contract.methods.retrieve().call({from: account.address, gasPrice: gasPrice, gas: gasEstimate}));
        console.log(await contract.methods.getRandom().call({from: account.address, gasPrice: gasPrice, gas: gasEstimate}));
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
})();


Output - 

store method
{
    blockHash: '0xac3bed99e723736a09eca7f802d5791a29a7035a6097fd5479121cfbf686dcd8',
    blockNumber: 20996462,
    contractAddress: null,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 782688,
    from: '0x62aacdd74659506d72ec55e9bc2342798e5929fb',
    gasUsed: 41383,
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    status: true,
    to: '0xc48a2e92f3f2066153a3eddf5071bc0c1ece0172',
    transactionHash: '0xc6706afddc18cdd3ccb9b9077a779aea1f72130bf33862b8c2c50714770139e3',
    transactionIndex: 7,
    type: '0x0',
    events: {}
}

retrieve method
5

getRandom method
5554097233048177814328041552358545131308099309008757005048758322173278412271
```